# unable to install Django 2.2.4 for python3.7.4 on Linux mint 19.1

Tags: python, django, pip, pipenv

I want to install Django web framework version 2.2.4 on the Linux. I'm using Linux mint 19.1 with python2 (default), python3.6.8 (default) and python3.7.4 (sudo installed from source).

I am using command `pipenv --python3.7 install django==2.2` to install but it's not working.

I tried this tutorial to install Django- [link to the youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/-oQvMHpKkms?t=603)

```
$ python3.7 -V
>>> Python 3.7.4

$ pip3 -V
>>> pip 19.2.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)




~ dev/try_django$ pipenv --python3.7 install django==2.2.4

Usage: pipenv [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try "pipenv -h" for help.

Error: no such option: --python3.7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `pipenv -h`, pipenv will print out its help page. Near the bottom, there will be some examples. Among these samples is:

```
Usage Examples:
   Create a new project using Python 3.7, specifically:
   $ pipenv --python 3.7
```

As you can see, you are missing a space between the `--python` and `3.7` parts.

Comment: pipenv --python 3.7 ( this command successfully created virtual environment!). Question- I made a specefic directory for my projects 'dev/try_django' and changed my directory to home/dev/try_django and again ran the command $pipenv --python 3.7 install django==2.2.4. This time process ran succesfully. However, upon running 'pipenv shell' command, i see the virtual enviroment being created in . /home/ankur/.local/share/virtualenvs/ankur-0RdmWIa8/bin/activate  ->There is no file inside dev/try_django looks like the virtual enviroment is running on user(ankur). It should be in (try_django)

Comment: help. I've been struggling to install Django for way too long.

Comment: I don't know exactly how pipenv works. If you want to know where it creates the virtual environment, I suggest you read pipenv's documentation: https://docs.pipenv.org/en/latest/

Comment: The only problem I seem to have right now is the location of virtualenv is not where I desired it to be. I wanted to run virtual environment in 'home/my dev/try_djnago directory' . Is it possible to change location of virtualenv?